# Xml Thowing weird exception

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have no idea what this exception is.  Just when I thought I was getting the hang of linq something like this happens.  I am getting this exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,TestImplementationIdeas.PatientClass]' to type 'TestImplementationIdeas.PatientClass'.
```

Now, I have know idea why this exception is being throw.

```
PatientClass template = (PatientClass)(from templates in xDocument.Descendants("template").Where
                                                       (templates => ((templates.Descendants("element").Attributes("name").ToString() == "EncounterId") && templates.Descendants("element").Attributes("value").ToString() == Enc.ToString())) //elem.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//templates/template[./elements/element[@name=\"PopulationPatientID\"and @value='{0}' and @enc='{1}']]",PopulationPatID, Enc))
                                                       select new PatientClass
                                                       {
                                                           PatientId = Convert.ToInt32("0" + templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PatientId']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                           EMPIID = Convert.ToInt32("0" + templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='EMPIID']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                           //public int PopulationPatientID { get; set; }
                                                           FirstName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='FirstName']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                           LastName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='LastName']").Attribute("value").Value,

                                                       });
            return template != null ? template : null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, LINQ queries always return an `IEnumerable<>` object, in your case, `IEnumerable<PatientClass>`.  You need to perform additional opertions to filter a collection to a single object.

```
//  will return the first `PatientClass` in the collection.  
//   And will throw an exception if the collection is empty.
return template.First(); 

//  will return the first `PatientClass` in the collection or return the default value       
//   (null in this case) if the collection is empty.
return template.FirstOrDefault(); 

// will return the only `PatientClass` in the collection if the collection only has 
//  one object and will throw an exception if it is empty or has more than 1 object.
return template.Single(); 

// will return the only `PatientClass` in the collection if the collection only has 
//  one object, the default value (null in this case) if it is empty and will throw an    
//  exception if it has more than 1 object.
return template.SingleOrDefault();
```

And instead of the `OrDefault()` methods, if you want to control what value is returned when it is empty, there is a `DefaultIfEmpty<>()` extension method that you can specify a value if the collection is empty.

```
// will return the first element in the collection, but if it is empty, 
//  it will return a new Patient class object created with the default constructor instead of a null
return template.DefaultIfEmpty(new PatientClass()).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to cast the IEnumerable return type from your Linq to type PatientClass - the CLR can not do that since they are not related types.

You need to add some more Linq there to return a single instance of PatientClass.

Answer (score 1):

Your LINQ query returns `IEnumerable<PatientClass>` which you are trying to cast to a single `PatientClass`.  If you really only want one object back from the query, call .First() on it

```
PatientClass template = (from templates in xDocument.Descendants("template").Where
                                                   (templates => ((templates.Descendants("element").Attributes("name").ToString() == "EncounterId") && templates.Descendants("element").Attributes("value").ToString() == Enc.ToString())) //elem.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//templates/template[./elements/element[@name=\"PopulationPatientID\"and @value='{0}' and @enc='{1}']]",PopulationPatID, Enc))
                                                   select new PatientClass
                                                   {
                                                       PatientId = Convert.ToInt32("0" + templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='PatientId']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                       EMPIID = Convert.ToInt32("0" + templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='EMPIID']").Attribute("value").Value),
                                                       //public int PopulationPatientID { get; set; }
                                                       FirstName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='FirstName']").Attribute("value").Value,
                                                       LastName = templates.XPathSelectElement("elements/element[@name='LastName']").Attribute("value").Value,

                                                   }).First();
```

Comment: Is there any way I can return a single type of my object?

Comment: Sequence contains no elements... That is the exception that I am getting now.

Comment: @DmainEvent - use FirstOrDefault instead if you want it to return null when there are no matches

Comment: Ah... Thanks for all the help.  I am doing my dambdest to grasp Linq... but because I am an idiot, I can't get it to sink into my skull.

Comment: Download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - it is great for learning this stuff...

Comment: +1 for linqpad.  just remember that certain methods return collections while other return single objects... and the ones that return single objects all have 'OrDefault' versions to use when you expect there to sometimes be no match

Comment: I am trying out LinqPad... but I run into similar problems :)